# Como añadir una select a una Tabla?

Tags: python, mysql

Hola estoy intentando añadir una select de una base de datos a una tabla con la funcion PrettyTable pero no me sale:

```
    tabla = PrettyTable()
    tabla.field_names= ['Codigo', 'Nombre', 'Procedencia', 'Altura', 'Peso', 'Posicion', 'Equipo']
    mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM jugadores")
    myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
    for x in myresult:
        myresult2=list(myresult)
        tabla.add_row
        print(tabla)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

En la linea `tabla.add_row`, no estás añadiendo nada al objeto `tabla`. Y en esta otra `print(tabla)` está dentro de un `for`, por lo que es obvio que va a imprimir toda la tabla por todos los registros que encuentre. Entonces, para arreglarlo:

```
# connection = pymysql.connect( ... )
# ...
tabla = PrettyTable()
tabla.field_names = ['Codigo', 'Nombre', 'Procedencia', 
    'Altura', 'Peso', 'Posicion', 'Equipo']

with connection.cursor() as mycursor:
    mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM jugadores")
    for x in mycursor:
        tabla.add_row(x.values())

print(tabla) # <-- fuera del for
```

Comment: También se puede directo desde el cursor de la conexión: `from prettytable import from_db_cursor` y luego `tabla = from_db_cursor(cursor)` Ver [la documentación](https://pypi.org/project/prettytable/#description) No hice pruebas con esa instrucción, pero puedes ojearla a ver si te resulta.

Comment: Me salio este error:'tuple' object has no attribute 'values',aqui msmo (x.values())

Comment: @Alberto en mi lógica cambio un poco la parte de mysql. Estoy iterando directamente sobre el cursor, lo cual devuelve un iterador con una estructura así: `{'Codigo':'COD01', 'Nombre':'Jugador 01', ... etc}` por cada fila, y en el `for` se le asigna a la variable `x`. Entonces para convertir eso a ['COD01', 'Jugador01', etc...] uso la instrucción `x.values()` ¿Estás usando pymysql? ¿Estás usando Python 3.10?